# Refering to a specific page in Wicket i18n properties file

Tags: internationalization, wicket

I am building my first ever Wicket project and I find that the amount of properties files in my code base is growing rapidly. Ideally I would like to contain all internationalization in a single file for each language/region. Just so I can find things easily.

I found out that my application properties file could be ideal for this. My application properties file is called `ApiAdminApplication.properties`. Now I am trying to add my translatables to this file, without making a mess of things.

According to the javadoc of `ComponentStringResourceLoader` this should be possible. Apparently the lookup order is as follows:

```
  page1.properties => form1.input1.Required
  page1.properties => Required
  form1.properties => input1.Required
  form1.properties => Required
  input1.properties => Required
  myApplication.properties => page1.form1.input1.Required
  myApplication.properties => Required
```

The second to last line contains the behavior I am looking for, but cannot get to work.

I have a page called `CustomerEditPage` which in turn contains a form with id `customerForm`

So here is what I am adding to `ApiAdminApplication.properties`, and what I think should work according to the snippet above:

```
CustomerEditPage.customerForm.name=Customer name
```

Sadly, this does not work. I can however get this to work by leaving out the page name, and starting with `customerForm`, but that is not what I want. I want per page internationalization contained in a single file.

Can anyone give me some pointers on this? Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Wicket 8.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the javadoc of ComponentStringResourceLoader is just wrong and should be fixed.

To accomplish what you need you will need to extend `ClassStringResourceLoader` and override [getResourcePath()](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/1a749e22eb33aa4ce9b99c6f22e9d87748ea7677/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/resource/loader/ComponentStringResourceLoader.java#L271). In your impl you will have to prepend the result with the name of the page that owns the Component passed as a parameter.

Then you will need to register your loader at `ApiAdminApplication#init()` method with:

```
getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(new MyClassStringResourceLoader(ApiAdminApplication.class))
```

see the [defaults](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/1a749e22eb33aa4ce9b99c6f22e9d87748ea7677/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/ResourceSettings.java#L222).

Please file a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/WICKET/issues so that the javadoc issue is fixed (or someone else who knows better than me how to accomplish this can explain us).

Comment: The bug report can be found here, one of the contributors seems to have fixed it. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-6610

Answer (score 0):

After reporting the bug I ended up doing what martin-g suggested, and extended `ClassStringResourceLoader`. For your convenience, here is what I did:

```
public class PrefixedStringResourceLoader extends ClassStringResourceLoader {

    public PrefixedStringResourceLoader(Class<?> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    protected String getResourcePath(final Component component) {
        final Class<? extends Page> parentClass = component.getPage().getClass();

        final String resPath = super.getResourcePath(component);

        if (!resPath.isEmpty())
            return String.format("%s.%s", parentClass.getSimpleName(), resPath);

        return parentClass.getSimpleName();
    }

}
```

There is a small gotcha to this. It always requires you to work with complete resource paths. This can be a bit tricky, I had some problems with the snippet below:

```
<input type="submit" wicket:id="save" wicket:message="value:save" />
```

This evaluated to `CustomerEditPage.customerForm.save.save`, where I expected it to become: `CustomerEditPage.customerForm.save`. This is not the case because the wicket:message actually becomes a child of the save form input.

I ended up going for:

```
<input type="submit" wicket:id="save" wicket:message="value:caption" />
```

Which evaluates to `CustomerEditPage.customerForm.save.caption`, which I find somewhat more readable. Of course, you could roll your own more advanced resource loader, but this one is good enough for me.